# Angular2 How to change values of data-toggle in html with *ngFor in Collapsible Div?

Tags: angular

I am trying to understand how to change values of data-toggle and data-target in HTML tag like Anchor Tag or DIV Tag with *ngFor.

I am trying to create a Nested Collapsible Side-Menu.
One of my List Tag is like this.

```
<li *ngFor="let group of data">  
    <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#toggleDemo0" data-parent="#sidenav01" class="collapsed"> {{group.name }}<span class="caret pull-right"></span>  
    </a>  
    <div class="collapse class=" category-background id="toggleDemo" style="height: 0px;">  
        <ul class="nav nav-list"><a href="#"><h5>{{queue.queueName}}</h5></a>  
            <ul *ngFor="let stationDetail of queue.stationDetails"><li><h5>{{stationDetail.stationName}}</h5></li>  
                <li>
                    <div class="row content">
                        <div class="col-md-4 newCount"><h5>{{stationDetail.newCount}}</h5></div>  
                        <div class="col-md-4 urgentCount"><h5>{{stationDetail.urgentCount}}</h5></div>  
                        <div class="col-md-4 onTrackCount"><h5>{{stationDetail.onTrackCount}}</h5></div>  
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
    </div>
</li>
```

Data is coming but I am not able to populate it the right way. I want the below way

```
queue1  
    some-data1  
   count1|count2|count3


    some-data2  
   count1|count2|count3  


queue2
   some-data3
count1|count2|count3
```

The way I am getting data right now is that I can expand the queue1 and see all data with static data-toggle id and data-target but not queue2 and queue3.

How can I correct this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have unique ids in your divs. You have
id="toggleDemo"
for all of them.

Use i as index in * ngFor and make your div ids using i as below:

*ngFor="let group of data; let i=index;

then may be use id="toggleDemo_{{i}}"